# Unable to update parent and nested records in rails because of unique index on multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I created a parent model with nested records through `has_many` association and allowed to update nested records through `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. 
My nested records have `order` attribute that should be unique in scope of parent_id. I know that I may use Rails uniqueness validation with `:scope` but I am determined to use unique multicolumn index.

So, let's say I've got parent model `Race`:

```
class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :drivers
  accept_nested_attributes_for :drivers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and nested `Drivers`:

```
class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :race
  validates :order, numericality: { only_integer: true,
                                    greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
end
```

I've got also my unique index created:

```
class AddUniqueIndexOnDriversOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :drivers, [:order, :race_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Unfortunately with this setup I am not able to change order of previously created `Drivers` in `Race`. When I want to update `Race` with `Drivers` and new perfectly valid order for every `Driver` record Rails does not perform this update as one transaction and my index interrupts whole operation. Any hint how to keep db constraints and be able to update parent object with nested records in one operation?

Comment: What code are you using to make the updates?  That can possibly be changed to make it work.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I've tried to use standard Rails method: `Race.update(race_params)`

Comment: I meant, which logic are you using?  Please show the block of code that makes the `update` call.  The whole block that deals with assigning driver order to races.  That's the key.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I just send all the records to the controller. Assuming this simple example, having one `Race` with `id:1` with two `Drivers` with `id: 1, order:1` and `id:2, order:2` in DB i want to update it and I send attributes to my controller: `race:{id:1, drivers_attributes:[{id:1, order:2}, {id:2, order:1}]}`. When rails updates nested driver with `id 1` there is a constraint violation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple hours of searching and digging I finally found the answer to my question! The solution uses `DEFERRABLE CONSTRAINTS` in database, something I hadn't been aware before.

These kind of constraints don't have to run immediately, they may perform their checks at the end of transaction.

This exact case is perfectly described in https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/deferring-database-constraints.